# Ubuntu 17.10 on Acer Cloudbook 14 ao1-431

Tags: boot, uefi, acer

I have purchased a cheap netbook with Windows 10 and have tested out various installations of Linux all running with varied success some better than others. 
I wanted to try out Ubuntu (64 bit version) on this Acer Cloudbook and have run into a roadblock. Booting from the USB stick and Live desktop works, installation works without issue. But when rebooting, I get a "No Bootable Device" screen.

I have installed with Secure boot off, secure boot on, have selected an UEFI file under EMMC/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi with typing out an optional boot description or simply typing "yes" and I still get the 'no bootable device'.

I have tested Linux Mint, Fedora, Ubuntu 17.04, Korora and elementary OS and all have worked prior to this version.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from an emergency/live disk and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Ok I ran the Boot Repair Utility and here is the URL :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25859284/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25867599/

Answer (score 0):

Try booting to an Ubuntu emergency disk, opening a Terminal window, and issuing the following command:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0005,2001,2002,2003
```

Note that the values here are for *your* system, as revealed in the `efibootmgr` output in your Boot Repair output. Specifically, I've added the `ubuntu` option (`Boot0005`, hence `0005`) to the front of the boot order list.

When you reboot, GRUB should appear and you should be able to boot; *however,* many computers have defective EFIs that will prevent this from working. If you continue to have problems at this point, you'll have to employ a fix or workaround, such as:

- **Reset firmware options to their defaults** -- Sometimes NVRAM data becomes damaged and resetting the firmware options to their defaults will clear enough out that the problem will go away. You'll need to dig around in your firmware setup utility to locate the appropriate option. Note, however, that the `ubuntu` entry in the boot order list is likely to disappear, so you may need to add it manually or run Boot Repair to completely re-install GRUB.
- **Update your firmware** -- If you're very lucky, your computer's manufacturer may have released a firmware update (probably called a "BIOS update" on their site) that fixes this problem. You can try installing it, then try fixing the boot order again. Sometimes this will wipe the boot options, just like the preceding fix, so you may need to manually add a boot option or run Boot Repair.
- **Return your defective computer for a refund** -- If neither of the preceding options helps, and if the computer is new enough, I recommend returning it to the store for a refund. Manufacturers have had ***YEARS*** to fix this very fundamental bug, so I cannot recommend giving your money to a manufacturer who hasn't fixed this problem. Of course, you may not have the option to return the broken computer for a refund if you bought it months or years ago, so....
- **Copy GRUB to the fallback position** -- EFI-based computers should boot from the fallback filename, `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` (case-insensitive) on the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) if no other boot entry is valid. Thus, you can copy GRUB (or Shim, if Secure Boot is active) to this location to get the boot to work. To do this, mount the ESP somewhere convenient in an emergency system, copy `EFI/ubuntu` at this mount point to `EFI/BOOT` at the same mount point, and rename `EFI/BOOT/shimx64.efi` to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. (You could instead rename `grubx64.efi` to `bootx64.efi` if you're sure you're booting with Secure Boot disabled.) This should get the system to boot, but subsequent updates to GRUB or Shim will not be properly installed unless you manually repeat this step.
- **Use `fbx64.efi`** -- The `fallback.efi`/`fbx64.efi` program is intended to help with your type of situation. If this program is installed using the fallback filename, it will look for `.CSV` files in subdirectories of `EFI` and, if they're found, read their contents and use that to re-create suitable boot entries and move them to the top of the boot order. Shim will also launch a matching `fbx64.efi` file if it's present, so you can copy `shimx64.efi` to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` and put `fbx64.efi` in `EFI/BOOT` to have it work with Secure Boot enabled. Setting this up manually is more of a pain than copying GRUB to the fallback filename, but it's a slightly cleaner solution in some respects. IIRC, Ubuntu 17.10 should set this up automatically, but your Boot Repair output lacks sufficient details to verify that this is the case on your system. (Unfortunately, Boot Repair lacks proper support for NVMe disks.)

Comment: Could you explain the command, especially since the paste links have expired?